# How to pad only the bottom of a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to pad only the bottom of a paragraph in HTML. To pad ALL sides you do this:

```css
p {
  border: 3px solid black; 
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>50 pixels padding all sides.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know how to only pad the bottom of the document? Is it possible?

Comment: use `padding: 0 0 50px 0;`

Comment: You want to pad the whole document? Or only the `<p>` element? You ask for both in the question. Also, what did you find when you looked for this on google?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this:

```css
p {
  border: 3px solid black; 
  padding-bottom: 50px; // padding-bottom property
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>50 pixels padding bottom.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the "padding-bottom" property

Source: [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the padding shorthand:

```css
padding: 0 0 50px 0; /* top, left, bottom, right */
```

```css
p {
  border: 3px solid black; 
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>50 pixels padding at the bottom only.</p>
</body>
</html>
```